# How to handle IE download popup using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popup, internet-explorer-11, autoit

I need a solution to download a PDF file from an web application in IE11 using selenium webdriver. Please find the below pop-up which I am trying to handle.

[image]

[image]

Below are the ways I tried handle the IE popup but unfortunately nothing helped.

1. I tried to handle this scenario using AutoIT using the below AutoIT script.

   Sleep(5000)

   Local $hIE = WinGetHandle("[Class:IEFrame]")

   Local $hCtrl = ControlGetHandle($hIE, "", "[ClassNN:DirectUIHWND1]")

   If WinExists($hIE,"") Then

   WinActivate($hIE,"")

   ControlSend($hIE ,"",$hCtrl,"{F6}")

   Sleep(500)

   ControlSend($hIE ,"",$hCtrl,"{TAB}")

   Sleep(500)

   ControlSend($hIE ,"",$hCtrl,"{enter}")

   EndIf

   Sleep(25000)

Though the above AutoIT script worked, but after execution of AutoIT script the webdriver scripts hangs up. Even a common system.out.println statement is not getting executed after handling the pop-up using above AutoIT script.

2. I tried to handle this pop-up using Robot class, but hard luck, that also not seems to be working.
3. I tried to disable this IE pop-up by doing some registry settings by going to the below path,
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\

   After doing certain registry settings, this pop-up is successfully getting disabled for .xlsx or .RDP files and not for .PDF files. But In my case I have a test case where I need to download a .pdf file and proceed with further webdriver scripts.

Guys, suggestion of any other workaround will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Sudheendran P L

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157 this approach can be used, it doesn't require any tools like AutoIt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Click button does not work properly in this case with IE. I switched clicking button for focusing it with `sendKeys()` and then pressing with Enter.

Try this:

```
Robot robot;
try {
        // pressing download button
        button.sendKeys("&quot;&quot;");
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        // handling download
        webDriver.wait(2000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        webDriver.wait(200);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can use `Thread.sleep()` instead of `driver.wait()` and should work as well.

Comment: The problem is robot doesn't work with Jenkins when it is running headless job.